# How to test a controller function calling a private function that in turn calls a asynchronous function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`[plunkr][1]`http://plnkr.co/edit/Jk1Rp3nEgUQTmDOs3xBl?p=preview

My current code is structured as below.

```
angular.module("app",[])
  .service("dataService",function($http){
    this.get = function (url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    };
  })
  .service("mainService",function(dataService){
    this.getData = function(pattern){
      return dataService.get(pattern+"/abc");
    }
  })
  .controller("mainController",function($scope,mainService){
    $scope.refreshData = function(pattern){
      loadData(pattern);
    }

  function loadData(pattern){
    mainService.getData(pattern)
      .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
})
```

I have been trying to make sense of how to test it by reading blogs but each blog has either a different approach or the blog is 2-3 years old. I would like to know how do I test the controller?

Should I test each function? If yes, then how should I test the private function? Is using the private function a good idea or should I just add the private function code to the scoped function?

Also is there any better way to do write this function?

Comment: You can stub `mainService` when you test controller - than expect that  `mainService.getData have` been called if you execute `$scope.refreshData()`

Comment: I created a jasmine spy for the main service as below.                `mainService = jasmine.createSpyObj('inboxService',['getData']);` But it is not setting a varaible on its success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important part where we are going to create stub:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    var $httpResponse = {
        success: function() {
            return $httpResponse;
        },
        error: function() {
            return $httpResponse;
        }
    };
    var _stubMainService_ = {
        getData: jasmine.createSpy('getData').and.returnValue($httpResponse)
    };

    angular.module('app')
        .value('mainService', _stubMainService_);
});
```

and test that uses it:

```
it('rereshes data', function() {
    var pattern = 'abcde';
    scope.refreshData(pattern);
    expect(mainService.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(pattern);
});
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .service("dataService", function($http) {
    this.get = function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    };
  })
  .service("mainService", function(dataService) {
    this.getData = function(pattern) {
      return dataService.get(pattern + "/abc");
    }
  })
  .controller("mainController", function($scope, mainService) {
    $scope.refreshData = function(pattern) {
      loadData(pattern);
    }

    function loadData(pattern) {
      mainService.getData(pattern)
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }).error(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  })

describe('mainController()', function() {
  var scope, controller, mainService, $q;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    var $httpResponse = {
        success: function() {
          return $httpResponse;
        },
        error: function() {
          return $httpResponse;
        }
      };
    var _stubMainService_ = {
      getData: jasmine.createSpy('getData').and.returnValue($httpResponse)
    };

    angular.module('app')
      .value('mainService', _stubMainService_);
  });


  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _mainService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('mainController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
    mainService = _mainService_;
  }));

  it('rereshes data', function() {
    var pattern = 'abcde';
    scope.refreshData(pattern);
    expect(mainService.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(pattern);
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried another method where I set the spyObj and in the end of the beforeEach block,I called scope.$apply. Then it worked and set the required variable.